# Does Python random.seed() and numpy.random.seed() implementations differ one from another?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random, random-seed

I'm experimenting a difference of a distribution of data when implementing CLT (Central Limit Theorem), comparing two approaches: one using pure Python and the other, Numpy.

Here's my code:

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy import mean
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# [With Numpy]
#
# Generate 1000 samples of 50 men, from 60 to 90 Kilos and calculate the mean
# of each sample, at once.
seed(1)
means = [mean(randint(60, 90, 50)) for _i in range(1000)]

# [Without Numpy]
#
# Generate 1000 samples of 50 men, from 60 to 90 Kilos.
# Calculate the mean of each sample, storing on a separated list.
random.seed(1)
samples = list()
for i in range(0, 1000):
    samples.append([random.randint(60, 90) for n in range(50)])
means_without_numpy = [sum(s) / len(s) for s in samples]

# Plot distributions of sample means, side by side.
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title("Numpy")
plt.hist(means)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title("Pure Python")
plt.hist(means_without_numpy)
plt.show()

print(f"The mean of means:                 {mean(means)}")
print(f"The mean of means (without numpy): {mean(means_without_numpy)}")
```

This code produces the following histograms and a message, after closing them:

[image]

```
$ python3 clt_comparisson.py 
The mean of means:                74.54001999999998
The mean of means (without numpy): 74.94394
```

My questions are:

1. Are the distributions (means from random datasets), affected by the way that each module (`random` and `numpy`), provide random data?
2. If the first question is true: since that I'm providing `1` as seed, should't they generate the same randomized datasets, since that they have a same seed value?

Comment: "should't they generate the same randomized datasets, since that they have a same seed value" - no, that's not how seeding works.

Comment: A seed (by range or value) does not imply the same PRNG algorithm is used. It is the actual algorithm that determines the quality of the sequence. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - the same algorithm with the same seed used twice should produce the same thing. Create `r1 = random.Random(b'My standard seed')` and `r2 = random.Random(b'My standard seed')` and both will produce the same numbers. `r1.randint(0, 100000) == r2.randint(0, 100000)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` and python's `random` use different algorithms, which I think is quite expected for a mathematics package written in C and fortran. The same algorithm with the same seed will produce the same values

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(12345678)
>>> import numpy.random
>>> numpy.random.seed(12345678)
>>> random.randint(0, 100000)
94406
>>> numpy.random.randint(0, 100000)
67251
```

(Not the same)

The distributions will vary slightly between the two implementations even over a huge range because you wouldn't expect the quality of randomness to be exactly equal between them. If you created a second dataset in the same program without changing the seed, it would vary a bit, as would a dataset with a different seed.

One wouldn't supply their own seed in a cryptographic setting, but on the science side, it can be useful if you want a model to be reproducible. In that case, base your code off of `numpy.random.RandState` with some well known 32 integer, so that you don't have to worry about the program wide `numpy.random.seed()` that others may need or can change.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the underlying PRNG is the same in both cases, though: it's Mersenne Twister. The specifics of seeding and random integer generation are different. Also, `random.randint` isn't a good match for `numpy.random.randint` - the former includes the upper endpoint, while the latter doesn't.

Comment: Finally, as of NumPy 1.18, `numpy.random.randint` is no longer the recommended way to generate integers; see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/new-or-different.html#new-or-different. The new way, with the default random NumPy generator, _does_ use a completely different PRNG from core Python. (A PCG64 variant.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson -Thanks for the info. I assumed that since numpy uses a 32 bit unsigned integer that it was disappearing into the bowels of some old fortran based rng. Now I know what's really going on.